# bitmaplist[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

the code here draw 5 grass image on the canvas on random places.i gave all the grass objects an unique name.Then i made a click event for every grass objecs which will show their individual names.

```
 bitmaplist[i].on('click',function vanish(event){

alert(bitmaplist[i].name);

 }
  );
```

but it keeps giving me error that bitmaplist[i] is undefined.what might be the reason for this problem and how it can be fixed?

FULL CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="easeljs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<script>
function makeit(){
  var bitmaplist=[];
  var i;
  var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
  var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  var image=new Image();
  image.src="grass.jpg";


  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   bitmaplist[i]=new createjs.Bitmap(image);


     bitmaplist[i].x=stage.canvas.width-Math.random()*900;
  bitmaplist[i].y=Math.random()*400;
  bitmaplist[i].name="grass"+i;
  bitmaplist[i].speed=Math.random()*5;
  bitmaplist[i].mouseEnabled=true;

  stage.addChild(bitmaplist[i]);
  stage.update();
    bitmaplist[i].on('click',function vanish(event){

alert(bitmaplist[i].name);

 }
  );
  }



}
window.onload=makeit;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/251311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this object:

```
bitmaplist[i].on('click',function vanish(event){
   alert(this.name);
});
```

Or using **target** property of [Event](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Event.html) object:

```
bitmaplist[i].on('click',function vanish(event){
   alert(event.target.name);
});
```

Read more here [EventDispatcher](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html)

Comment: it giving error this.getAttribute("name")/event.target.getAttribute("name") is not a function

Comment: If it's not DOM Object try plain name:
event.target.name or event.currentTarget.name